# iOS 5 Core Data freeze

Tags: iphone, core-data, ios5

I try to do the following simple thing:

```
NSArray * entities = [context executeFetchRequest:inFetchRequest error:&fetchError];
```

Nothing fancy. But this freezes in iOS 5, it works fine in iOS 4. I don't get exceptions, warnings or errors; my app just simply freezes.

Please help me out! I'm dying here! ;)

Comment: Does it freeze or does it crash? It can't do both. If it crashes there will be a crash log or stack trace.

Comment: You're not sharing the context between threads, are you?

Comment: @Dries - I'm also investigating this cause I'm finding the same behavior. If you run on the 4.3 Simulator does it work fine (mine does) ? On the 5.0 Simulator it locks up regularly with no error message or debug info.

Comment: I don't have an answer yet, but I have tracked down the fact that when it hangs, if you're running under the debugger and  you break the app, it stops at the executeFetchRequest line. If you then examine the managedObjectContext (context) in your case, I found one of the internal vars _objectStoreLockCount set to 2. This tells me that its waiting on a lock.

Comment: Its definitely an issue around the way iOS5 handles concurrency now - Am having a good look at my code, and its not looking pretty

Comment: It's definitely a concurrency issue. I've just found in my code where I was making a change on an object retrieved on the main thread but being changed (and "saved") in a background block

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but my _objectStoreLockCount is 1...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for the hints given in this page on how to solve this freezing issue which appeared on upgrading from iOS4. It has been the most annoying problem I have found since I started programming on iOS.

I have found a quick solution for cases where there are just a few calls to the context from other threads.

I just use **performSelectorOnMainThread**:

```
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stateChangeOnMainThread:) withObject: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:state, @"state", nil] waitUntilDone:YES];
```

To detect the places where the context is called from another thread you can put a breakpoint on the NSLog on the functions where you call the context as in the following piece of code and just use **performSelectorOnMainThread** on them.

```
if(![NSThread isMainThread]){
     NSLog(@"Not the main thread...");
}
```

I hope that this may be helpful...

Comment: I'm getting the same freezing but I'm definitely not threading anything so calling performSelectorOnMainThread doesn't change anything.

Comment: Well, maybe it is a different problem. If you pause the debugger when the App freezes you will see the place where it has stopped. If you have an access to CoreDataModel Context from a thread different form Thread 1 then it is the seme problem and you can fix it this way. Otherwise you may need to further search for the problem in order to identify and solve it.

Answer (score 19):

I don't know if you also use different Thread. If yes the issue comes from the fact that NSManagedObjects themselves are not thread-safe. Creating a ManagedContext on the main thread and using it on another thread freezes the thread.

Maybe this article can help you :
http://www.cimgf.com/2011/05/04/core-data-and-threads-without-the-headache/

Apple has a demo application for handling Coredata on several threads (usually main & background threads) : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TopSongs/Introduction/Intro.html

What I've done to solve this issue is :

- In the application delegate : create the persistent store (one for all thread) and create the Coredata managed Context for the main thread,
- In the background thread, create a new managed context (from same persistent store)
- Notifications are used when saving, to let the mainContext know when background thread has finished (inserting rows or other).

There are several solutions, using a NSQueueOperation. For my case, I'm working with a while loop. Here is my code if it may help you. However, Apple documentation on concurrency and their Top Songs example application are good points to start.

in the application delegate :

```
 -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.cdw = [[CoreDataWrapper alloc] initWithPersistentStoreCoordinator:[self persistentStoreCoordinator] andDelegate:self];
    remoteSync = [RemoteSync sharedInstance];

    ...

    [self.window addSubview:navCtrl.view];
    [viewController release];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES; 
}    

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    if (persistentStoreCoordinator == nil) {
        NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.persistentStorePath];
        NSLog(@"Core Data store path = \"%@\"", [storeUrl path]);
        persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil]];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error];
        NSAssert3(persistentStore != nil, @"Unhandled error adding persistent store in %s at line %d: %@", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}


-(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    if (managedObjectContext == nil) {
        managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:self.persistentStoreCoordinator];
    }
    return managedObjectContext;
}

-(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    if (persistentStoreCoordinator == nil) {
        NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.persistentStorePath];
        NSLog(@"Core Data store path = \"%@\"", [storeUrl path]);
        persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil]];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error];
        NSAssert3(persistentStore != nil, @"Unhandled error adding persistent store in %s at line %d: %@", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}


-(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    if (managedObjectContext == nil) {
        managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:self.persistentStoreCoordinator];
    }
    return managedObjectContext;
}


-(NSString *)persistentStorePath {
    if (persistentStorePath == nil) {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths lastObject];
        persistentStorePath = [[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mgobase.sqlite"] retain];
    }
    return persistentStorePath;
}

-(void)importerDidSave:(NSNotification *)saveNotification {
    if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
        [self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:saveNotification];
    } else {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(importerDidSave:) withObject:saveNotification waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}
```

In the object running the background thread :

```
monitor = [[NSThread  alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(keepMonitoring) object:nil];

-(void)keepMonitoring{
    while(![[NSThread currentThread]  isCancelled]) {
        NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];    
        AppDelegate * appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        //creating the cdw here will create also a new managedContext on this particular thread
        cdwBackground = [[CoreDataWrapper alloc] initWithPersistentStoreCoordinator:appDelegate.persistentStoreCoordinator andDelegate:appDelegate];
        ...
    }
}
```

Hope this help,

M.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. If you run under the debugger and when the app "hangs" stop th app (use the "pause" button on the debugger. If  you're at the executeFetchRequest line, then check the context variable. If it has a ivar _objectStoreLockCount and its greater than 1, then its waiting on a lock on the associated store.

Somewhere you're creating a race condition on your associated store.

Answer (score 4):

This really sounds like trying to access a `NSManagedObjectContext` from a thread/queue other than the one that created it.  As others suggested you need to look at your threading and make sure you are following Core Data's rules.

Answer (score 3):

Executing fetch request must happen from the thread where context was created.

Remember it is not thread safe and trying to `executeFetchRequest` from another thread will cause unpredictable behavior.

In order to do this correctly, use

```
[context performBlock: ^{
     NSArray * entities = [context executeFetchRequest:inFetchRequest error:&fetchError];   
}];
```

This will `executeFetchRequest` in the same thread as context, which may or may not be the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the app would freeze before 'executeFetchRequest' without any warning. The solution was to wrap all db operations in @synchronized(persistentStore).
Eg:

```
NSArray *objects;
@synchronized([self persistentStoreCoordinator]) {
            objects = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete all object with fetchrequest doesn't work for me, the sqlite looks corrupted. the only way I found is

```
    //Erase the persistent store from coordinator and also file manager.
    NSPersistentStore *store = [self.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores lastObject];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *storeURL = store.URL;
    [self.persistentStoreCoordinator removePersistentStore:store error:&error];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:&error];

    //Make new persistent store for future saves   (Taken From Above Answer)
    if (![self.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        // do something with the error
    }
```