# executeFetchRequest:error: freezes app

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I don't know what it is but it happens when is fetching elements, well that's what I asume because the app just freezes, I pause the debugging and the debugger stops at a `return [__context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];` Any help about this will be very appreciated.

Comment: Tentatively, I would suggest breaking that line into 3 or 4, at least for debugging purposes: Declare an NSArray instance to receive the results, check if there's an error and if the array is non-null, and only then return the array.

Comment: I'll give it a try and tell you what happened, thanks in advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807977/ios-5-core-data-freeze) basically you'll need to lock your persistentStoreCordinator because read only calls aren't thread safe. Apple documentation mention this [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html). Cheers my friend!